# Calculating period power and average power

Tags: power

```
v(t) = 5cos(50*pi*t)V

i(t) = 3sin(50*pi*t)A
```

a. What is the energy per period?

b. What is the power averge per period?

I calculated the period time and I got 0.04sec.
than I did an integrael beween 0 to 0.04 on v(t)*i(t) and got zero.

because of a I also got zero in b because b is (w/T).

Is my way true ?

Comment: Is it a homework? If it is then could you please show your effort i.e. what you've tried so far, where you're stuck at.

Comment: You right. I edited.

Comment: Graph out the waveform and judge for yourself if it makes sense. https://www.desmos.com/calculator And don't forget about reactive power. Also remember you don't have a resistor here where power is always dissipated regardless of the direction of current (because voltage always changes polarity to match if the current direction changes).

Comment: Well, you have a pure sine and a pure cosine so, if you got anything else than zero, I would worry.

Comment: Don't mix with "apparent" power ...

Answer (score 0):

A sinewave multiplied by a cosine wave of the same frequency has an average value of zero. So if cosine represents voltage and sine represents current, because they are 90° out of phase, the average power equals zero.

> *What is the energy per period*

- If the period is one second then the energy per one second is the average power consumed over than period.
- If the period is (say) ten seconds then the energy per ten seconds is 10 times the average power over that period.

> *What is the power average per period*

It's the true representation of billable power i.e. it's the basis on what your electricity meter operates.